# Single Sign On and Database Queries

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I have a mssql database with a users table and tables for about 6 different applications.  Each application has it's own schema inside the database.  When a user logs in, the user is show a list of applications that he has rights to.

I would like to separate the user tables and applications into their own databases for two main reasons.

1. Scalability
2. Maintenance

The first step in the project is to move the users table into it's own database.  Then use web api services to allow any application to interact with the data.  For example - IsUserValid, CreateUser, UpdatePassword....

The issue I see is that some of the apps have stored procedures that call the user table with a join.  For example:
    SELECT user.username, user.firstname, user.lastname, app.column1, app.column2 from                                                                                                         users inner join app on users.username = app.username

Is there an elegant way to solve this?  I know that I can join two tables in two separate databases, but I would like to be able to move app databases and the user databases onto separate servers.

Comment: This is the same problem I had before by wanting to use the asp_net membership database (since it had all bunch of cool functionality).  You cannot FK from a different database.  One proposed solution was to create a dbo.UserInfo table in each database.  And we would create users in the asp_net membership database......THEN had a small utility that would "link" asp_net users with Applications.  But in our "linking" we wrote only the PK for Users into the seperate application databases.  Thus each db had its own "copy" that it would FK off of.  We also included a "soft-delete" status column

Comment: when a user got "unlinked" from an application.  (You could write more code to cascade-delete info in each application db (when a user was removed from the asp_net memberhship database).......but we just used a soft-delete tag.

Comment: Another note.  We kept the MyApplication.dbo.UserInfo table very "slim".  Just the FK to asp_net memmbership (Users) table.  And the soft delete tag.  If we had extra "property data" about any User in the specific Application database, we had an extra MyApplication.dbo.UserExtraInfo table.  That's debatable, but that's what we rolled with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always create [linked servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx) and query data across multiple servers.

```
SELECT * FROM schema.Table1 t1 JOIN server2.schema2.Table2 t2 ON t1.UserId = t2.UserId
```

Alternative solutions would be to use some sort of replication to copy the data across all databases or modifying the procedures so they do not rely on the user data.